# Cesium WMS layer issue

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs, wms

Hi all I am trying to get a WMS layer on my cesium globe.  Below is the code I am using.  When I look at the network tabs I do see the request going through all at 200 and when I use the links on the requests they do work; however, it says their file size is 0kb and I receive this error :

An error occurred in "p": Failed to obtain image tile X: 0 Y: 0 Level: 1.
etc.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

var provider = new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
       url : url',
       layers : 'bm'
 });

viewer.imageryLayers.addImageryProvider(provider);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it was a CORS issue.  If you add the filters in 
geoserver/webapp/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<!-- Uncomment following filter to enable CORS -->
   <filter>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

<!-- Uncomment following filter to enable CORS -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

and add the jetty servlets in geoserver/webapp/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib it will fix this issue.  Download for the servlets is here: 
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/

See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/enabling-cors-in-geoserver-jetty for more info.